# Lenovo G 580 can't access BIOS set up..what could be the cause?

Tags: windows-10, bios

I tried using the Novo button still nothing

Tried to remove the bios battery for about 10 still nothing

Tried using fn+f2,f2,fn+f12,f12 all the possible button for Lenovo still nothing

Comment: Does it boot to Windows? If it boots to Windows 10, what if you instruct Windows 10 to boot to Firmware (BIOS/UEFI) from within Settings - Recovery - Advanced Startup options? Disable Fast boot in Power options (If already enabled)  and retry. Remove the Laptop Battery if you can (Not BIOS battery) and re-insert and retry.

Comment: I did that also but still doesn't show anything.the bios met be corrupt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lenovo article
[Recommended way to enter BIOS](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/ec/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-g-series-laptops/lenovo-g580-notebook/solutions/ht500216)
lists four methods.

If your computer boots too fast, the Windows method will be the easiest:

- Enter *Settings > Update & security > Recovery*
- Click "Restart now"
- In the "Options" menu click "Troubleshoot"
- Select "Advanced options"
- Click "UEFI Firmware Settings"
- Choose "Restart"
- The computer will now boot into the BIOS.

If this didn't work, the BIOS might be corrupted, but cannot be entered
in order to do a reset.

The solution would then be to install the latest BIOS version, downloaded
from the manufacturer's website.
For the poster, this was from the
[G580 Laptop Support](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/fr/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-g-series-laptops/lenovo-g580-notebook/20157/downloads/driver-list/component?name=BIOS%2FUEFI).

Comment: Tried that also..I suppose now it something wrong with the bios itself it met be corrupt

Comment: You may try to update the BIOS [from here](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/fr/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-g-series-laptops/lenovo-g580-notebook/20157/downloads/driver-list/component?name=BIOS%2FUEFI). Perhaps the Windows 8 setup will still work on your Windows 10.

Comment: Yeah it worked after bios update thanks

Comment: Came here to say thanks for the bios update suggestion and links. My dad's G580 had a corrupt BIOS and the OS had been updated to Windows 10. I was able to get the BIOS back by updating using the Windows 8 BIOS update for August 2013. Now I can access the boot menu and  bios

Answer (score 0):

Start up the computer and allow it to fully start.

Now Restart the computer.

Watch it very carefully.

At some point (early in the restart, the screen will say

"Press Enter to enter Setup"

Do that and you get into BIOS.

"Restart" slows down the boot process, so F1 (repeated presses) may work also.

If you continue to have difficulties, you need to contact Lenovo Support.

Comment: Still can't access the Bois set-up

Comment: You should call Lenovo Support at this point.

Answer (score -1):

Create usb (must be smaller than 2Gb) in FAT, put inside bios file in cap format bios.cap.(i use rufus with free dos).
You can download bios from lenovo, but only 2013 version is in cap format,
it is inside exe file: `62CN97WW.cap`.
Rename file to `bios.cap`.
Push button <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> and power-on with battery inside and external power.
Therefore can you see usb blink and monitor go up with update bios, after reboot get in bios for own configuration.